# how to use (drop zone for multi images) this php code in yii 2.0 framework

Tags: javascript, php, yii2-advanced-app

how to use (drop zone for multi-images) this PHP code in Yii 2.0 framework. I am a new developer in Yii
Thanks

form.php

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>PHP - Multiple Image upload using dropzone.js</h2>
            <form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="image-upload">
                <div>
                    <h3>Upload Multiple Image By Click On Box</h3>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

action file

```
$uploadDir = 'uploads';

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
 $tmpFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $filename = $uploadDir.'/'.time().'-'. $_FILES['file']['name'];
 move_uploaded_file($tmpFile,$filename);
}
```

script code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.imageUpload = {
        maxFilesize:1,
        acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif"
    };
</script>
```

Yii Files

form.php

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'status')->dropDownList([ '1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No']) ?>

 <?= $form->field($model, 'images')->fileInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

Comment: hey can you tell how did you get `dropzone uploaded files` in controllers, using `$_GET` or `$_POST` method ?

Comment: in Controller file   `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())  ) {           
            if (!empty($_FILES)) {                
             $tmpFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
             $filename = 'image-'.time().'.'. $_FILES['file']['name'];                     
             $uploadDir = Yii::getAlias("@dropzoneDir").'/'.$filename;
             move_uploaded_file($tmpFile,$filename);
            }
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {  return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model,]);
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to define add dropzone in form:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>`
 <script src="../../assets/dropzone/js/dropzone.js"></script>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
         href="../../assets/dropzone/css/dropzone.css">

  <div action="" id="dZUpload" class="dropzone" method="post" 
     enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="dz-default dz-message">Drop files here to upload or click</div>
 </div>
```

after that add js for dropzone:

```
  <scirpt>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var url = "http://locahost/url/createpage";

    console.log(url);
    $('#dZUpload').dropzone({

        url: url,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        maxFiles: 5,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        enqueueForUpload: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        autoDiscover: false,
        parallelUploads: 5,
        clickable: true,
        maxFilesize: 100,
        acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/png",

        success: function (file, response) {
            var imgName = response;
            file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
            console.log("Successfully uploaded :" + imgName);
        },

        init: function () {

            var myDropzone = this;

            myDropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {
              alert("new file added");
            });

            myDropzone.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) {
                this.removeFile(file);
            });

            var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit");

            submitButton.addEventListener("click", function (file) {

                if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {

                    var submitfiles = false;

                    if (submitfiles === true) {
                        submitfiles = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    file.preventDefault();

                    var deleted_image_data = document.getElementById('deleteImage').value;
                    myDropzone.on('sending', function (file, xhr, formData) {
                        formData.append('deleted_image_data', deleted_image_data);
                    });

                    myDropzone.processQueue();

                    myDropzone.on("complete", function () {
                        submitfiles = true;
                        $('#submit').trigger('click');
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: can you give your submit button id as `submit`

Comment: i have to give it as like  but it can't work                                             
  `<div class="form-group col-md-12" id="submit">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>`

Comment: when I have click on submit button then in console show this error `Navigated to http://localhost:8081/traveling/backend/web/index.php?r=gallery%2Fcreate
common.js:10  http://localhost:8081/traveling/uploads/dropzone`

Comment: and common.js at line 10 line is `var url = " http://localhost:8081/traveling/uploads/dropzone";`

Comment: does it uploaded in dropzone?

Comment: not upload in the dropzone folder let me explain there Url is what for.. its an URL of image save folder or it's a action

Comment: the did you try to fetch `$_FILES` in controller

Comment: code is work in backed so you have to work in backed for that check this: http://www.dropzonejs.com/ you get your solution